# Docker: df -h output in bash from ubuntu

Tags: docker

When I run the following docker command:

```
docker container run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

I get a bash shell, when I type in df -h I get the following output:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                      106G   63G   38G  63% /
tmpfs                         64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                        1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  106G   63G   38G  63% /etc/hosts
shm                           64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                        1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                        1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /sys/firmware
```

The overlay is 106 GB where is it getting this number from?

Comment: What is the output of `df -h` on your host system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comes from the storage driver and how it implements the layered filesystem. For the overlay storage driver, it is using files in /var/lib/docker on the host, and your available disk space is based on free space in that filesystem. In your environment, based on the bind mount line for /etc/host, that appears to be the same as the root filesystem on your host.